# Xcode 4.2 switch statement bug?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

[image]

BUT! add a random statement before:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: That's been around for ages; you can't start a case block with a declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a switch-statement bug, it's a limitation in the C language. In C, the first statement after a case label cannot be a variable declaration. You can get around this by either declaring the variables before the switch statement or creating the variable inside a block of code (see below). Obviously, you can also re-order your code (if possible) so that another statement comes before the variable declaration.

Example 1:

```
CGRect newRect = CGRectZero;
switch( var ) {
  case 0:
    // do some stuff
    break;
  case 1:
  default:
    newRect = [someVar someMethodThatReturnsARect];
    // other code
    break;
}
```

Example 2:

```
switch( var ) {
  case 0:
    // do some stuff
    break;
  case 1:
  default: {
    CGRect newRect = [someVar someMethodThatReturnsARect];
    // other code
    break;
  }
}
```

Example 3:

```
switch( var ) {
  case 0:
    // do some stuff
    break;
  case 1:
  default:
    // some code re-ordered to here
    CGRect newRect = [someVar someMethodThatReturnsARect];
    // rest of the other code
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checked Kernighan&Ritchie for this. In the C specification is no line describing
that a declaration in the the first statement of a 'case' is not allowed.

However most people consider it good programming to not declare values in a 'case'.

I think that the b) issue from 
[EXC_BAD_ACCESS in statement block in Switch impact on imageViewPoistion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141212/exc-bad-access-in-statement-block-in-switch-impact-on-imageviewpoistion)
is related to the same bug.