# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in statement block in Switch impact on imageViewPoistion

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, switch-statement, parentheses

I have a strange situation. I get an exception on the following code on the close curly brackets of the switch statement

```
imageViewPosition = self.imageView6.center;
switch(direction) {
   case(1): 
      if (starty-imageViewPosition.y>50) {
         imageViewPosition.y = starty+100;
      } else {
         imageViewPosition.y = starty;
      }
      break;
   case(2): 
      ...
   }         <----- Here i get the exception
```

starty is a double class member. And imageViewPosition is a CGPoint.
When I run it like this, I get a EXC_BAS_ACCESS exception.

In the following cases I get no exception and everything works as expected.
I don't understand why that is the case.

a) When I add parentheses to the if statement, everything works fine:

```
if ((starty-imageViewPosition.y)>50) {
```

b) When I place the case statement within curly brackets everything works fine.

```
imageViewPosition = self.imageView6.center;
switch(direction) {
   case(1): {
      if (starty-imageViewPosition.y>50) {
         imageViewPosition.y = starty+100;
      } else {
         imageViewPosition.y = starty;
      }
      }
      break;
```

Why? I expect that the answers to the a) and b) options will be different.
I had this already earlier in another situation with a switch, so I want to
understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like something else is going on. Are you sure some of your instances are not being deleted by the garbage collector while the switch is running? It happens sometimes when defining properties as "weak".

Comment: Maybe it helps to add the programming language to your question (or even better as a tag)

Comment: @Rafael That is the strange thing, in the 2 examples everything is working as expected. No memory leaks etc.